# Groovy Nested (Recursive?) XML

Tags: groovy

Given a list of objects that contains an ID and an ELEMENT, I need to iterate over the list and produce XML that looks like this:

```
<object id="1">
    <element>...</element>
    <object id="2">
        <element>...</element>
        <object id="3">
            <element>...</element>
            </object>
        </object>
    </object>
```

Note each object is created WITHIN the previous object, and objects are only closed off at the end of the list. (Not my choice, dictated by an external interface)

Is there a way to produce this using the XML Markup Builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyElement {
  def id
  def element
}

def list = [new MyElement(id: 1, element: "element1"),
            new MyElement(id: 2, element: "element2"),
            new MyElement(id: 3, element: "element3")]

println new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
  def foo // note declaration and initialization on different lines
  foo = { List<MyElement> l ->
    if (l.isEmpty()) return
    def head = l.head()
    def tail = l.tail()
    object {
      id head.id
      element head.element
      foo(tail)
    }
  }
  foo(list)
}
```

Output (prettified):

```
<object>
  <id>1</id>
  <element>element1</element>
  <object>
    <id>2</id>
    <element>element2</element>
    <object>
      <id>3</id>
      <element>element3</element>
    </object>
  </object>
</object>`
```